# reposition the elements of the Navbar in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am new to Bootstrap.

In Bootstrap 4 I would like to use a fixed-toped branded Navbar. The Navbar should show the Brand, 6 nav items and a dropdown:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item6</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On large viewports the page will be displayed in a container of 1,200 px width.

I would like to modify the horizontal positions of the Navbar elements so that the 6 nav items are centered horizontally in the 1,200px container, the brand element ends at the left beginning of the container and the dropdown element starts at the right ending of the container:

[image]

On smaller viewports the Navbar should follow its standard behavior i.e. it should collapse and show the hamburger (which integrates the 6 menu items as well as the dropdown) and the brand element should start horizontally on the left side of the viewport.

How can I implement this?

**EDIT:**

This code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

gives this result:
[image]
The changes are:

- a `<div class="container">` after `<nav...>`. This gives the 1200 px container.
- two `<ul class="navbar-nav">` instead of one. This separates the 6 nav-items from the dropdown.
- the first `<ul class="navbar-nav">` uses `m-auto`. This centers the 6 nav-items and pushes the dropdown to the right.

However the result is not as it should be. The brand element should end at the left beginning of the centered 1200px and the dropdown element should start at the right ending of the centered 1200px:

[image]
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add class `mx-lg-auto` on the div`.navbar-nav`

mx-auto will center your element while the `lg` part will check if the viewport width is at 1200px or greater.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/oLet2w6k/

Bootstrap doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer I modified the code and the question. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-0" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center text-left">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nav-item dropdown flex-row justify-content-md-center justify-content-start flex-nowrap">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dropdown item 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer I modified the code and the question. Please see the edited question.